# How to display discontinuous line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, raphael, rickshaw

I need a javascript library where I can really easily  display two dimensional data in the form of a line chart. I need to display discontinuous lines. I've looked at a few libraries, but they do much more than I want. I tried with Rickshaw, but it accepts only a series.

Let's say I have this data:

```
 long_short_data = [
{
  key:'round_1_1',
  color:"#468966",
  values:[
    {
      label:"user_0",
      value:31
    },
    {
      label:"user_1",
      value:93
    }
    ]
},
{
  key:'round_1_2',
  color:"red",
  values:[
    {

    },
    {
      label:"user_1",
      value:34
    }
    ]
}
```

];

Here I want that the `round_1_2` basically to start from the second tick. I've used this data with `nvd3`'s stackedmultibarcharts, but I need to represent it in the form of line chart/time series.

Comment: So what's the question? Does NVD3 do what you want to do?

Comment: I was not able to display segments of time series with NVD3. I would like to have a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203241/representing-no-value-in-array-in-google-visualization). If anybody else has the same problem you will understand how the data is constructed if you check out the [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous).

Comment: If the problem is null in your dataset, you can get around it by computing the missing data points manually, (d1 + d2) / 2.

Comment: My point was not to display anything, aka specifically interrupt the line